# Working Rpi Hotspot but can't get ethernet/internet to work

Tags: networking, wireless, ethernet

I've set up my pi as a wireless hotspot and am trying to share my Mac's internet via ethernet.

The hotspot side of things works ok and if I have my mac's wifi (or even internet sharing) turned off I can ping and ssh with the Pi via ethernet.

As soon as I enable internet sharing on the mac, I lose the ethernet connection.

Anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have internet sharing turned off, and things work, that implies that either you have set up static IPs, or you are running a DHCP server on the pi side of the ethernet. I'm guessing the latter. If you share your mac's wifi connection over ethernet, the mac will be expecting to act as a DHCP server, not a client.

Either way, your pi is now sitting there as either a static IP or a DHCP server, but definitely not a DHCP client, which is why it's not working. You need to reconfigure your eth0 to be a DHCP client. You need

```
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

in /etc/network/interfaces

You likely have

```
iface eth0 inet static
```

which won't work in this case.